# How to clearfix while preserving collapsing margins?

Tags: html, css

I have something like:

```html
<div style="margin-bottom: 10px">
  <div style="overflow: auto">
    <div style="float: left">
      <div style="margin-bottom: 10px">
        foo
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If I removed `overflow: auto`, the alignment gets messed up because this needs clearfix. If I don't remove it, the margins don't collapse. In other words, I want the total `margin-bottom` to be `10px`, not `20px`.

Is this even possible?

Comment: and why you need float to start with?

Comment: Look into Flexbox. You can easily create horizontal alignments without floating your items. I realize that this may just be for testing but it's better to use a stylesheet vs inline styles for ease of maintenance too.

Comment: why not use flex and padding? instead of float and margin?

Comment: @plumwd Flexboxes have the same issue, plus the downside of not working on 1% of browsers

Comment: @TemaniAfif to put two block elements side-by-side

Comment: @Pete I prefer margins because they collapse

Comment: *to put two block elements side-by-side* then technically you can no more have margin collapsing as you will need to use something different than *block* element (float, inline-block, flexbox,etc) and there is no margin collpasing with such element